# How to print a image name that is inside a loop in python and export all the prints into excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, opencv, image-processing

I have a image comparison script.

How can I print the image name every time it loops?

Also, can I print both images measurements?

And the most important part: how can I export all the printed stuff into excel, and in the first column I need to show the image name?

Thanks

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load all image names into a list
ls_imgs1_names = os.listdir("Images1") 
ls_imgs2_names = os.listdir("Images2") 

# construct image paths and save in list
ls_imgs1_path = [os.path.join("Images1", img) for img in ls_imgs1_names]
ls_imgs2_path = [os.path.join("Images2", img) for img in ls_imgs2_names]

# list comprehensin to load imgs in lists
ls_imgs1 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs1_path] 
ls_imgs2 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs2_path]

for original in ls_imgs1:
    for image_to_compare in ls_imgs2:

        # compare orignal to image_to_compare
        # here just insert your code where you compare two images
        # 1) Check if 2 images are equals
        if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
            print("The images have the same size and channels")
            difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

        cv2.imshow("difference", difference)

        print(cv2.countNonZero(b))
        if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) ==0:
            print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
            


    # 2) Check for similarities between the 2 images
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
    kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)


    index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
    search_params = dict()
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

    good_points = []
    ratio = 0.9 # mai putin de 1 
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < ratio*n.distance:
            good_points.append(m)

    # Define how similar they are
    number_keypoints = 0
    if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
        number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
    else:
        number_keypoints = len(kp_2)
    print("Keypoints 1ST Image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
    print("Keypoints 2ND Image: " + str(len(kp_2)))
    print("How good it's the match: ", len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100, "%")
    #print(original.name)
    #print("Title:" +title)
    percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
    print("Similarity: " + str(int(percentage_similarity)) + "%\n")
```

This is the format needed:
[image: This is the format needed]

The below method works but it is comparing all the images with all the images(4 images in a folder and 4 images in a folder it exports 16 line). I only need 4 lines, one for each comparison, I mean image1 from folder Images1 compared to Image1 from folder Images2, etc.
Also need only the name without the path Ex: Images1\Image1 => Image1

Any ideas?
[image]

If I am using this version I can compare different images, how can I adapt the final code to work in the same way?

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load all image names into a list
ls_imgs1_names = os.listdir("Images1") 
ls_imgs2_names = os.listdir("Images2") 

# construct image paths and save in list
ls_imgs1_path = [os.path.join("Images1", img) for img in ls_imgs1_names]
ls_imgs2_path = [os.path.join("Images2", img) for img in ls_imgs2_names]

# list comprehensin to load imgs in lists
ls_imgs1 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs1_path] 
ls_imgs2 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs2_path]

for original in ls_imgs1:
    for image_to_compare in ls_imgs2:

        # compare orignal to image_to_compare
        # here just insert your code where you compare two images
        # 1) Check if 2 images are equals
        if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
            print("The images have the same size and channels")
            difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

            cv2.imshow("difference", difference)

            print(cv2.countNonZero(b))
            if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) ==0:
                print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
            


    # 2) Check for similarities between the 2 images
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
    kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)


    index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
    search_params = dict()
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

    good_points = []
    ratio = 0.9 # mai putin de 1 
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < ratio*n.distance:
            good_points.append(m)

    # Define how similar they are
    number_keypoints = 0
    if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
        number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
    else:
        number_keypoints = len(kp_2)
    print("Keypoints 1ST Image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
    print("Keypoints 2ND Image: " + str(len(kp_2)))
    print("How good it's the match: ", len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100, "%")
    #print(original.name)
    #print("Title:" +title)
    percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
    print("Similarity: " + str(int(percentage_similarity)) + "%\n")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would like to mention the possible error in your code.

- If `original` and `image_to_compare` variables shapes are not equal, the error will occur. Since both `difference` and `b` variables are not defined. Therefore, if you reformat your code:

  - ```py
    if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
        print("The images have the same size and channels")
        difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
        b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

        cv2.imshow("difference", difference)

        print(cv2.countNonZero(b))
        if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) ==0:
            print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
    ```

> How can I print the image name every time it loops?

- You need to get the data from both `ls_imgs1_path` and `ls_imgs2_path` variables. You can use a counter to print the current images. For instance:

  - ```py
    for i1, original in enumerate(ls_imgs1):
        for i2, image_to_compare in enumerate(ls_imgs2):
            print(ls_imgs1_path[i1])
            print(ls_imgs2_path[i2])
    ```
  - If you are working in Mac, one possible problem is `.DS_Store`

    - ```py
      if (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs1_path[i1]) and (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs2_path[i2]):
          print(ls_imgs1_path[i1])
          print(ls_imgs2_path[i2])
      ```

> Also, can I print both images measurements?

- Do you mean printing dimensions? If so:

  ```py
  for i1, original in enumerate(ls_imgs1):
    for i2, image_to_compare in enumerate(ls_imgs2):
        if (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs1_path[i1]) and (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs2_path[i2]):
            print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs1_path[i1], ls_imgs1[i1].shape))
            print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs2_path[i2], ls_imgs2[i2].shape))
  ```

  - Example result:

    - ```py
      Name: Images1/baboon.png, dimensions: (512, 512, 3)
      Name: Images2/1.png, dimensions: (427, 640, 3)
      ```

> And the most important part: how can I export all the printed stuff into excel, and in the first column I need to show the image name?

- You have multiple choices, `xlswriter`, `pandas`, etc.
- For instance: `xlswriter` ([source](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html))

  - Initialize the writer variables:

    - ```py
      workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/Users/ahx/Desktop/images.xlsx')
      worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

      row = 0
      col = 0
      ```
- Assume you want to write image-name and the image-shape

  - Initialize the list variable

    - ```py
      result = []
      ```
  - Append the values in the loop

    - ```py
      for i1, original in enumerate(ls_imgs1):
          for i2, image_to_compare in enumerate(ls_imgs2):
              if (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs1_path[i1]) and (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs2_path[i2]):
                  print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs1_path[i1], ls_imgs1[i1].shape))
                  print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs2_path[i2], ls_imgs2[i2].shape))

                  result.append([ls_imgs1_path[i1], ls_imgs1[i1].shape])
                  result.append([ls_imgs2_path[i2], ls_imgs2[i2].shape])
      ```
  - Write the values to the excel

    - ```py
      for name, shape in result:
          worksheet.write(row, col,     name)
          worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(shape))
          row += 1


      workbook.close()
      ```

Updated-request1

---

> I want only the name, without the extension

- Create an extension variable: `extension = ".jpg"`
- Then inside in the loop, replace the extension with an empty string

  - ```py
    img_name1 = ls_imgs1_path[i1].replace(extension, "")
    ```
  - But what happens if you have multiple different extensions?

    - Create a list i.e. `extension = [".jpg", ".png"]`
    - If the current name contains the extension, replace the extension with the empty string.

      - ```py
        for ext in extension:
            if ext in ls_imgs2_path[i2]:
                img_name2 = ls_imgs2_path[i2].replace(ext, "")
        ```

      or more efficiently

      - ```py
        img_name2 = [ls_imgs1_path[i1].replace(ext, "") for ext in extension if ext in ls_imgs2_path[i2]][0]
        ```

> the percentage that I need to export into the excel file

- First define the percentage variable and set to 0. (Just for initialization)

  - ```py
    percentage_similarity = 0
    ```
- From what I understand, to calculate the similarity, compared image shapes must be equal. If their `countNonZero` values for each channels are same, then set `percentage_similarity` to 0.

  - ```py
    if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) ==0:
        print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
        percentage_similarity = 100
    ```
  - Otherwise get the final calculation, store it in the `result` list.

    - ```py
      result.append([img_name2, ls_imgs1[i1].shape, ls_imgs2[i2].shape, percentage_similarity])
      ```
  - We have to update the writing to excel loop:

    - Create the column names:

      - ```py
        worksheet.write(0, 0, "Name of the image")
        worksheet.write(0, 1, "Image 1 dimension")
        worksheet.write(0, 2, "Image 2 dimension")
        worksheet.write(0, 3, "Similarity percentage")
        ```
    - Update the loop

      - ```py
        for name, shape1, shape2, similarity in result:
            worksheet.write(row, col,     name)
            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(shape1))
            worksheet.write(row, col + 2, str(shape2))
            worksheet.write(row, col + 3, str(similarity) + "%")
            row += 1
        ```

Updated-request2

---

> I want to compare image1 from 1st folder with image1 from 2nd folder; 2nd image from 1st folder with 2nd image from 2nd folder

- To achieve that, we need to combine the lists, we can use `zip`.

  - ```py
    for original, image_to_compare in zip(ls_imgs1, ls_imgs2):
    ```

> and also would love without the path "Images1\Image1" => Image1

- ```py
  img_name = img_name.replace("Images1/", "")
  ```

Code:

---

```py
import os
import cv2
import xlsxwriter

# load all image names into a list
ls_imgs1_names = os.listdir("Images1")
ls_imgs2_names = os.listdir("Images2")

# construct image paths and save in list
ls_imgs1_path = [os.path.join("Images1", img) for img in ls_imgs1_names]
ls_imgs2_path = [os.path.join("Images2", img) for img in ls_imgs2_names]

# list comprehensin to load imgs in lists
ls_imgs1 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs1_path]
ls_imgs2 = [cv2.imread(img) for img in ls_imgs2_path]

extension = [".jpg", ".png"]

result = []

i = 0  # counter

for original, image_to_compare in zip(ls_imgs1, ls_imgs2):
    if (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs1_path[i]) and (".DS_Store" not in ls_imgs2_path[i]):
        print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs1_path[i], ls_imgs1[i].shape))
        print("Name: {}, dimensions: {}".format(ls_imgs2_path[i], ls_imgs2[i].shape))

        img_name = [ls_imgs1_path[i].replace(ext, "") for ext in extension if ext in ls_imgs1_path[i]][0]
        img_name = img_name.split(os.sep)[1]
        percentage_similarity = 0

        # compare orignal to image_to_compare
        # here just insert your code where you compare two images
        # 1) Check if 2 images are equals
        if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
            print("The images have the same size and channels")
            difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

            cv2.imshow("difference", difference)

            print(cv2.countNonZero(b))
            if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
                print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
                percentage_similarity = 100
            else:
                # 2) Check for similarities between the 2 images
                sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
                kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
                kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)

                index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
                search_params = dict()
                flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
                matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

                good_points = []
                ratio = 0.9  # mai putin de 1
                for m, n in matches:
                    if m.distance < ratio * n.distance:
                        good_points.append(m)

                # Define how similar they are
                number_keypoints = 0
                if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
                else:
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_2)
                print("Keypoints 1ST Image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
                print("Keypoints 2ND Image: " + str(len(kp_2)))
                print("How good it's the match: ", len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100, "%")
                # print(original.name)
                # print("Title:" +title)
                percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
                print("Similarity: " + str(int(percentage_similarity)) + "%\n")

        result.append([img_name, ls_imgs1[i].shape, ls_imgs2[i].shape, percentage_similarity])
        i += 1

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('result.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 1
col = 0

worksheet.write(0, 0, "Name of the image")
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Image 1 dimension")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "Image 2 dimension")
worksheet.write(0, 3, "Similarity percentage")

for name, shape1, shape2, similarity in result:
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(shape1))
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, str(shape2))
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, str(similarity) + "%")
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you help me adjust it a little?
I am looking for a specific format (edited the original post. 
The name of the file can be 1st or 2nd, doesn't matter since they have the same name, but I want only the name, without the extension

Comment: Also, I see that your code is missing "    percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
    print("Similarity: " + str(int(percentage_similarity)) + "%\n")", being the percentage that I need to export into the excel file

Comment: See "Updated-request" part.

Comment: It works but it is comparing all the images with all the images(4 images in a folder and 4 images in a folder it exports 16 line). I only need 4 lines, one for each comparison, I mean image1 from folder Images1 compared to Image1 from folder Images2, etc.

Comment: and also would love without the path "Images1\Image1" => Image1

Comment: any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I have read it again and again and again and can't understand why is looping so many times :)

Comment: Lets start with the desired-output. What should be the `Name-of-the-image` column values? Like in the example, what should be the `Image1`, `Image2` .. values? Give me an example.

Comment: check the image attached in the description, that is exactly the desired output. Folder Images1 contains image1, image2, image3, folder Images2 contains image1, image2, image3;  I want to compare image1 from 1st folder with image1 from 2nd folder; 2nd image from 1st folder with 2nd image from 2nd folder, etc.

Comment: Ex: 
Images1      Images2
image1.jpg   image1.jpg
image2.jpg   image2.jpg
image3.jpg   image3.jpg
------------------------------
results:
image1 vs image1
image2 vs image2
image3 vs image3

Comment: So you want to compare each image from each folder? Like Images1/image1 vs Images2/image1,  Images1/image2 vs Images2/Image2, Image1/image3 vs Image2/Image3?

Comment: No no. let's say we have 2 folders: Animals1 and Animals2. in each folder we have: dog.jpg, cat.jpg, horse.jpg. I want to compare dog from 1st folder with dog from the second folder, cat from the 1st folder with cat from the second folder and horse from the 1st folder with horse from the second folder. Basically, both folders contains images with the same names and I want to compare every image with each correspondent image from the 2nd folder

Comment: Let me try again: First comparison should be Animal1/dog.jpg vs Animal2/dog.jpg, Second comparison should be Animal1/cat.jpg vs Animal2/cat.jpg and the third comparison should be Animal1/horse.jpg vs Animal2/horse.jpg?

Comment: Yes, that's right! 4 images in each folder, results 4 comparations => 4 output lines in the excel files

Comment: And name of the image columns will hold the following values: 1. dog vs dog, 2. cat vs cat, 3. horse vs horse?

Comment: Column name will be :1) dog; 2)cat; 3)horse. I don't need the name from the both folders given the fact that they are the same. I have updated the description with the output that it gives now and marked with red the output desired.

Comment: Please see `Updated-request2` part or you can directly use the code (updated)

Comment: Great! But the names still contains the path" Images1/image1" :)

Comment: In the excel file?

Comment: Yes. Name of the image
Images1\te
Images1\te1
Images1\te2
Images1\te3

Comment: I have updated my code, could you please try again?

Comment: It is possible to modify this project in order to compare the images if they have different dimensions? let's say 1000x1000 vs 950x950?

Comment: I guess if you remove the `if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape` sentence and reformat the code, then it may work for images with different dimension

Comment: What do I need to reformat exactly? The entire code? Can you help me with an example please?

Comment: Just delete the line, if you don't have any error then you dont need to reformat

Comment: line 86, in test
    difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-8ely825f\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:669: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

Comment: So, if images have different dimension then subtract method is not working.

Comment: So that means there is no possible way to compare them?

Comment: I guess no. I don't know whether SIFT algorithm will work even if you remove the subtract method

Comment: I have updated the description. If I am using this first version I can compare different images, how can I adapt the final code to work in the same way?